# Resize Background-image in unorderedlist (li)

Tags: html, css

I have a unordered list, that is a certain size per line, and each line has a background, I want the background to be resized and fit perfectly (scaled down) to fit the width of the box, I have tried and can't get it to work, I have made a simplified version of what I have here in this JSFiddle -

https://jsfiddle.net/p91vef0j/

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li style='border: 1px solid black; background: url(http://i67.tinypic.com/xlcq5w.jpg)'>
    <span style="background-color: #000000">
      Marvel's Avengers Assemble - S3E1 </br>
      Adapting to Change
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
li{
  list-style:none;
  color: white  ;
  padding-left: 0pt;
  margin-top:0px;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 60px;
  width: 270px;
}   

ul {
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
}
```

Hopefully someone can get the image scaled into the box for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are setting the `background-size: cover` in CSS but are setting `background` via inline styles. [`background`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background) is a short-hand property which includes the following:

- `background-size`
- `background-color`
- `background-image`
- `background-position`
- `background-repeat`
- `background-attachment`

When you set a value to `background` property, the URL is applied to the `background-image` and the other properties are set to their initial value. The below is what the [spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-backgrounds-3/#the-background) says:

> Given a valid declaration, for each layer the shorthand first sets the corresponding layer of each of ‘background-image’, ‘background-position’, ‘background-size’, ‘background-repeat’, ‘background-origin’, ‘background-clip’ and ‘background-attachment’ ***to that property's initial value***, then assigns any explicit values specified for this layer in the declaration. Finally ‘background-color’ is set to the specified color, if any, else set to its initial value.

This prevents your `background-size` (set via CSS) from having any effect. 
You should either set the `background-image` directly using inline styles (or) set the `background-size` also again.

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 0pt;
  margin-top: 0px;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 60px;
  width: 270px;
}
ul {
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li style='border: 1px solid black; background: url(http://i67.tinypic.com/xlcq5w.jpg); background-size: cover;'>
    <span style="background-color: #000000"> Marvel's Avengers Assemble - S3E1 <br> Adapting to Change</span>
  </li>
  <li style='border: 1px solid black; background-image: url(http://i67.tinypic.com/xlcq5w.jpg);'>
    <span style="background-color: #000000"> Marvel's Avengers Assemble - S3E1 <br> Adapting to Change</span>
  </li>
  <li style='border: 1px solid black; background-image: url(http://i67.tinypic.com/xlcq5w.jpg); background-size: 100% 100%'>
    <span style="background-color: #000000"> Marvel's Avengers Assemble - S3E1 <br> Adapting to Change</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Note:** You may want to consider changing the `background-size` value also. `cover` option scales the image while maintain its aspect ratio. So, if the aspect ratio of image is different from that of `li`, image would get cropped at the right and/or bottom. If you want to avoid cropping, you could use `100% 100%` as value (like in the 3rd `li` in the above snippet).

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand, the backgroud-image lines are coming from a php foreach statement, so they need to be defined inline, are you saying I need to set the size inline and not via css? Can you maybe show me it "fixed" in my fiddle? Thanks for taking the time to help me..

Comment: Ok, I see your examples now, sorry I on my phone, will try and mark as answer in a bit. Thanks so much.

Comment: Legend, your last edit with the 100% 100% has accomplished what I am after :) thank you so much for taking the time to help me. :)

Comment: Ah, I never upvote, just vote as the answer, I feel bad for people I didn't upvote before now :(

Comment: @user3768497: I see. I was only kidding as you called me *Legend* (people should never be asking for vote) but thanks for voting :) That said, you should generally consider using votes because they are also an indicator on how useful the answer was. You can even vote for multiple answers in the same thread provided they were all useful but it is not mandatory to vote on all posts.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to set the image as the background, why not use the img element to display the image inside of the li. Then set the text and img to `position:absolute;` and set the li to `position:relative;`. Also you will need to set the text and img to `top:0px;`.

```css
li{
  list-style:none;
  color: white ;
  padding-left: 0pt;
  margin-top:0px;
  position:relative;
  } 
  li img{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
  }
  li span{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
  }

ul {
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li style='border: 1px solid black;'>
    <img src="http://i67.tinypic.com/xlcq5w.jpg"/>
    <span> Marvel's Avengers Assemble - S3E1 </br> Adapting to Change</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```